# Django query aggregation with multiplication

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there an effective way to aggregate some query by multiplying field value in each model instance? For now I use this:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(some_bool_field=True)
ratio = 1
for item in queryset:
    ratio *= item.some_int_field
return ratio
```

Best way would be to do this same way as aggregation with sum, like in Django docs:

```
ratio = MyModel.objects.filter(some_bool_field=True).aggregate(Sum('some_int_field'))
```

Only instead of Sum() function I would like to do multiplication.

I am concerned about performance with my current way of doing this, because view I want to put this code into will be highly used and MyModel table will be changed very often.

I would like to avoid writing my own SQL expressions, because I'm not familiar with this language.

Comment: I got as far as trying qs.extra(select={'log':"log(cast(some_int_field as float))"}) but it won't let me aggregate(Sum()).  If you can manage that, then it's just doing e^your_sum to get the multiple.  Logfunction in postgres is fast.

Comment: ORMs are leaky abstractions. They reduce boilerplate code, but you still need to know what SQL does.